# Time series forecasting with 53 weeks in a year?

Tags: r, time-series, seasonality

I am building a time series model in R. I have four years of data from 2010 to 2013 and doing forecasting for 2014. According to the calendar that my organisation follows, in 2014 there would be 53 weeks, while the other years have only 52 weeks. How can I handle this kind of scenario in R?

Comment: At least one of those weeks is a bit short, though... right? Or does your organization's 2014 have 371 days in it?

Comment: Creating some average seasonality will be probably the best solution IMO

Comment: Weeks are annoying. Without more details on what are you trying to do (especially, what kind of seasonality you want in your model) it is hard to say what to do. For example, in walmart kaggle contest, figuring out how Christmas period interacts with weeks was [extremely important](https://www.kaggle.com/c/walmart-recruiting-store-sales-forecasting/forums/t/8028/a-key-adjustment).

Comment: You can use Kalman Filter, Holt-Winters Exponential smoothing, or ARIMA models to deal with seasonal data. It is difficult to answer your question when we do not know what variables or periods you are predicting

Comment: @Glen_b For accounting purposes, many organizations assign full calendar weeks (often Mon-Sun) to the calendar (or accounting year) in which the majority of their days fall.

Comment: @whuber thanks. It would be good to have it made explicit if this is the case here. Explaining how to handle things like this differing number of weeks would depend on being confident of exactly what the situation was --- which my initial comment was seeking to provoke a response on (I was expecting a correction of my premise in some form from the OP which would highlight exactly how they accounted for weeks)